# Можно ли ещё сократить запись "a = a === x ? y : x"?

Tags: javascript

Дана переменная `a` и постоянные `x`, `y`

```
const x = 1;
const y = 2;
let a = x;
```

Если `а` равна одной из них, то должна стать равной другой.

Можно ли это записать короче, чем так:

```
a = a === x ? y : x;
```

?

Тип данных может быть любым, проверка строгая.

P.S. Не тестовое, просто самому интересно.

Comment: `a = (x + y) - a`

Comment: @RomanKonoval без скобок будет короче. а если и пробелы убрать, то ещё лучше:)

Comment: @RomanKonoval для `x = 4444444444444444, y = 5555555555555555` результат будет слегка неожиданным.

Comment: @Yaant у меня всё нормально запустилось с алгоритмом @RomanKonoval для чисел :) Вы наверное имели ввиду `x = 0.4444444444444444, y = 0.5555555555555555`, тогда ответ действительно немного меняется и выдаётся `0.5555555555555556` вместо одних пятёрок после нуля :)

Comment: @roman-konoval читаем внимательно: Тип данных может быть любым. Например, объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае нет, но если такое у вас часто встречается и вы хотите упростить переключение между несколькими значениями, то можете написать такое:

```js
console.log('VALUES 2 ---------------------------');

const x = '1';
const y = 2;
let a = x;
const values = new Map([[x, y], [y, x]]);

a = values.get(a);
console.log(a, typeof a);

a = values.get(a);
console.log(a, typeof a);

a = values.get(a);
console.log(a, typeof a);

console.log('VALUES 4 ---------------------------');

const x1 = '1';
const x2 = 2;
const x3 = {b: 'Three'};
const x4 = ['Four'];

let value = x1;
const valuesMap = new Map([
  [x1, x2],
  [x2, x3],
  [x3, x4],
  [x4, x1],
]);

value = valuesMap.get(value);
console.log(value, typeof value);

value = valuesMap.get(value);
console.log(value, typeof value);

value = valuesMap.get(value);
console.log(value, typeof value);

value = valuesMap.get(value);
console.log(value, typeof value);

value = valuesMap.get(value);
console.log(value, typeof value);
```

- Почему использовал `new Map()` вместо обычного объекта? Потому что у обычного объекта в роли ключа не может быть любой тип данных, а у `new Map()` может.
- Так же этот метод можно спокойно расширять чтобы переключаться между 3-мя, 4-мя и более значениями.
- Почему не просто через `switch case` раз уж используется дополнительный код? Во первых так лаконичнее, во вторых `switch case` нельзя динамически расширять в дальнейшем, но если, конечно, у вас всегда будут заранее известное кол-во переключений и переключения не будут в дальнейшем меняться (в случае с 2-мя данными такое, конечно не провернёшь, но если будет 3 переключателя, то может понадобиться переключаться в обратном порядке например), то можете использовать и `switch case`, но лично я буду ссылаться на лаконичность `new Map()`

Comment: это, конечно, далеко не сокращение ))), но ответ очень интересный. обдуманный и дельный. Спасибо!

Comment: @DraKoan понимаю) Но это сильно сокращает кол-во проверок и потворного кода, если много где используется. А для единочного случая этот вариант, конечно не подходит)

Comment: Ваш ответ очень хорош тем, что показывает как применить Map для самых простых случаев. Отсюда его можно расширять на любые векторные графы данных. В голову сразу приходят идеи о запутанных многомерных лабиринтах с одним входом и выходом.

Comment: @DraKoan спасибо за хороший отзыв) Буду крайне благодарен, если посчитаете нужным отметить мой ответ как правильный!

Comment: Конечно отмечу, если не появится ещё более превосходного. Я подожду ещё день-два других ответов.

Comment: @DraKoan Разумно!)

Answer (score 1):

Всё же ответ: нет.

```
а = a !== x ? x : y;

а !== x ? a = x : a = y;

a = (a => a !== x ? x : y)(a)

a = new Map([[x, y], [y, x]]).get(a);

а = (а => [x, y].find(v => v !== a))();
```